Prevent render in editor via PHP
Simple ACF Gutenberg Block that I would like to use as a wrapper for other content (using <InnerBlocks />). The block's only field is a Link that wraps all of the content in an <a> tag.
Works great in on the page. This makes it difficult to edit win the Editor, however, because selecting any of the wrapped elements triggers the link.
Is there a value I can check in the PHP render script that will let me suppress the <a> tag when it's being used in the Editor (as opposed to on a page)?
